# hashlib "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Tags: python

I'm trying to build an Flask API in python that returns me the text that I sent to the API in a hashed version. But while hashing I get the following error: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

this is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import hashlib

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class hashing(Resource):
  def get(self, text):
    hash = hashlib.sha256(text('utf-8'))
    text_hashed = hash.hexdigest()
    return {"data":text_hashed}

api.add_resource(hashing, "/hash/<text>")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: can you please also share the output from the terminal just below your code ? my initial guess is that u are indeed trying to call a text string. i wanna know which line is complaining so that i can help

Comment: Yes "line 12, in get
    hash = hashlib.sha256(text('utf-8'))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: i see - the `text` is a str right? how can u call a string with a () ? that wont work  - i tried adding an example, but Stack has wierd endering wrt comments, so check the edits on this one for some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` is the actual string that's passed to the `hashing` method. I'm guessing you meant to call `encode` on it, not use it as a function:

```
hash = hashlib.sha256(text.encode('utf-8'))
```